# Change UISwitch's state from an NSObject class

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, allocation

I can't access to my labels, sliders and switches which are all in a UIViewController from my NSData Class.

this is my code so far :

**FirstViewController.h**

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController 
@property (strong) IBOutlet UISwitch * mySwitch;
@property (strong) IBOutlet UISlider *myTransitionSlide;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *labelTest;
```

**myNSDataClass.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>
@class FirstViewController;


@interface myNSDataClass : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate,CBPeripheralManagerDelegate>
{
    FirstViewController *firstViewController;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) FirstViewController *firstViewController;
```

**myNSDataClass.m**

```
- (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral didReceiveWriteRequests:(NSArray *)requests
{
    self.firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc]init];
    [[self.firstViewController labelTest]setText:@"text changed"];                                                  
    [self.firstViewController.myTransitionSlide setValue:1];
    [self.firstViewController.mySwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
}
```

I know that the problem come from the reallocation of FirstViewController but I don't know what I should do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't access your outlets from anywhere else but from the view controller that owns them. Also, you'd want do make your outlets `weak`.

To solve your problem you could use notifications:

```
- (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral didReceiveWriteRequests:(NSArray *)requests
{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MyAppDidReceiveWriteRequestNotification" 
                                                       object:nil 
                                                     userInfo:@{@"text": @"text changed", @"switchOn": @(NO)}];
}
```

Then, in your `FirstViewController`, you register yourself as an observer for that notification, for example in `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(handleDidReceiveWriteRequestNotification:)
                                                 name:@"MyAppDidReceiveWriteRequestNotification"
                                               object:nil];

}
```

And you implement the handler:

```
- (void)handleDidReceiveWriteRequestNotification:(NSNotification *)note
{
  [self.labelTest setText:note.userInfo[@"text"]];
  [self.mySwitch setOn:[note.userInfo[@"switchOn"] boolValue] animated:YES];
}
```

And you clean up:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

That's it. Much cleaner.

Also, you'd want to turn the name of the notification and the names of the userInfo dictionary keys into constants so that you don't have the same string literal in multiple places in your code.

Comment: This is the cleanest solution so far, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can make it works by adding reference to your FirstViewController.
In FirstViewController.m add property or private variable for myNSDataClass object, for example:

```
//FirstViewController.m
@implementation FirstViewController {
    myNSDataClass *_myData;
}
```

and later in viewDidLoad add reference to FirstViewController:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    //Your code here...
    _myData = [[myNSDataClass alloc] init];
    _myData.firstViewController = self;
}
```

The next step is removing memory leak, change your myNSDataClass.h to:
@class FirstViewController;

```
@interface myNSDataClass : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate,CBPeripheralManagerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, weak) FirstViewController *firstViewController; //<- use assign if you support OS < 4
//your code ..
@end
```

You don't need @synthesize in implementation file if you don't support OS less that 4.

Comment: That only needs the problem of the unnessessary and erroreous new allocation of something to the allocation of the myNSDataClass object

Comment: But there's no official support of iOS versions prior to iOS 4.3 which is installed on 2-3% of all iOS devices. What are you talking about when mentioning the support of OS less than 4?

Comment: @SergiusGee I'm talking about iOS 4.3 which support ARC - with OS less than 4.3 you cannot use weak keyword.

Answer (score 1):

When you know that the problem comes from the re-allocation, then don't reallocate it. 
It is that simple. :-)

Instead of that you need somewhere to set the `firstViewController` property of your `myNSDataClass` accordingly. That may happen in that very moment when your `firstViewController` is actually instanciated. Where that is depends on the architecture of your app.

If you want it 'neat' then don't let the `myNDataClass` (which might serve as model) access `mySwitch` etc. directly. Let it call some method of `firstViewController`. Only your view controller shold "know" its controls and set them accordingly.

Declaring these method(s) in `firstViewController.h` should do the trick. However, it would be even neater if you declare them in a protocol which `firstViewController` implements (confirms to). Instead of including `firstViewConroller.h` in `myNSDataClass.h` you should include this protocol (a .h file too).

Answer (score 1):

set a breakpoint before `[self.firstViewController.mySwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];` and there you should find the problem. If you print out `self.firstViewController.mySwitch`, the element should be **nil**.

So try to set primitive or initialized attributes at this point

for example

// FirstViewController.h

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
{
    BOOL switchState;
    NSString *lblTitle;
    float sliderValue;
}

-(void)setSwitchState:(BOOL)pSwitchState andLabelText:(NSString *)pLblTitle andSliderValue:(float)pSliderValue;
```

// FirstViewController.m

```
-(void)setSwitchState:(BOOL)pSwitchState andLabelText:(NSString *)pLblTitle andSliderValue:(float)pSliderValue
{
    switchState = pSwitchState;
    lblTitle = pLblTitle;
    sliderValue = pSliderValue;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.labelTest] setText:pLblTitle];                                     
    [self.myTransitionSlide setValue:pSliderValue];
    [self.mySwitch setOn:pSwitchState animated:YES];
}
```

and in peripheralManager

```
- (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral didReceiveWriteRequests:(NSArray *)requests
{
   // I don't know if this re-initialization is realy required, so I let it here.
   // If not, you should think of init it somewhere else use the solution with the NSNotificationCenter ;)
   self.firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc]init];
   self.firstViewController setSwitchState:NO andLabelText:@"text changed" andSliderValue:1];
}
```

Comment: You are still creating a new instance of `FirstViewController` every time the `peripheralManager:didReceiveWriteRequests:` method is called.

Comment: I don't know the rest of his code, so I left this part in the hope, that it's required to do so and he knows what he is doing there ;) otherwise I would also recomand a delegate solution